# convert hyphened url to controller action in cakephp 3. Like add-user should call users/add and so on for every controller and action

Tags: routes, cakephp-3.4

I want to create route to run contoller and action separated by hyphen(-) instead of calling controller/action. I tried below code :

```
Router::scope(
    '/add-user',
    ['controller' => 'Users'],
    function(RouteBuilder $routes){
        $routes->connect('', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add']);
        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    }
);
```

But using this I will have to create a route for each controller and action. I want something which can work for all. Thanks.